# pg_trgm not working on non-Latin and macOS

Tags: postgresql, locales

Trigrams don't work for non-Latin languages on the Mac.

On the Mac, I'm getting the following behavior:

```
select show_trgm('peace') -> {"  p"," pe",ace,"ce ",eac,pea}
select show_trgm('über')  -> {0xb1fa7d,0x0d7f89,0x4f84fe,ber,"er "}
select show_trgm('שלום')  -> {}
```

After trying with the default collations and getting the empty results, I tried changing to a UTF-8 collation, which still doesn't work.

```
postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
   Name    | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
-----------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 testdb    | tomer | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres  | tomer | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 template0 | tomer | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/tomer         +
           |       |          |             |             | tomer=CTc/tomer
 template1 | tomer | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/tomer         +
           |       |          |             |             | tomer=CTc/tomer
```

I'm using postgresql 14 on macOS 13.4.

Running the third query **works** on a postgres 13 instance in AWS RDS, with the UTF-8 encoding, collation and ctype.

```
select show_trgm('שלום')  -> {0x46e146,0x64182e,0x8c40cc,0x9c1fe2,0xda89ec}
```

I tried running this statement on both machines:

```
select * FROM ts_debug('english', 'שלום');
```

On the Mac, I got

```
 alias │ description   │ token │ dictionaries │ dictionary │ lexemes 
═══════╪═══════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪════════════╪═════════
 blank │ Space symbols │ שלום  │ {}           │ NULL       │ NULL
```

On the cloud server, I got

```
 alias │    description    │ token │  dictionaries  │  dictionary  │ lexemes 
═══════╪═══════════════════╪═══════╪════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════
 word  | Word, all letters | שלום  | {english_stem} | english_stem | {שלום}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the CTYPE setting for the English locale on MacOS considers Hebrew characters as white space. PostgreSQL doesn't have its own locale definitions, it uses the ones from the operating system.

I recommend creating the database with the Israeli locale `he_IL.utf8` or, if PostgreSQL was built with ICU support, use an ICU locale.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think it's correct... running `locale -a` returns lots of UTF-8 locales, including en_US.UTF-8 and the database is also created correctly. Otherwise, I would have probably received an error like the one that is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296828/set-lc-collate-and-lc-ctype-on-macos